# Finding an angle between vector and plane?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Determine the acute angle between the vector $$x =(1, 2, -1),$$ and the plane containing the lines $$r:(5, 0, 0) + t(-1, 1, 2)$$ and $$s:(5, 0, 0) + u(3, 1, 1)$$

There is a lot going on here for me and I don't know what to do first. Do I find the normal? Use cross/dot product? Pointing me in the right direction is all I need..

Comment: Finding the normal would be a great start.  Then $\frac {\mathbf x\cdot n}{\|x\|\|n\|} = \cos \theta$  where $\theta$ is the angle between the vector and the normal.  And once you have that, what is the angle between the vector and the plane?

Comment: The notation is somewhat confusing, in that $(5,0,0)$ is used to denote a point(?) and other triples of coordinate seem to denote directional "vectors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direction vectors are $(-1, 1, 2)$ and  $(3, 1, 1)$

Find  the cross product of these vectors to get the normal vector to the plane.

Find the angle between the  normal vector and  $(1, 2, -1)$ using the dot product.

If the angle is not acute, subtract it from $\pi$

That is the desire angle.